# Export variables to another script

Tags: linux, bash

I am making 2 scripts. The first script is going to take a file, and then move it to a directory named "Trash". The second script will recover this file and send it back to it's original directory. So far I have the first script moving the file correctly.
Here is my code so far:

For delete.sh

```
FILE=$1
DATEDELETED=$(date)
DIRECTORY=$(pwd)
mv $1 Trash
echo $FILE
echo $DATEDELETED
echo $DIRECTORY
```

Output:

```
trashfile
Sun Mar 2 21:37:21 CST 2014
/home/user
```

For undelete.sh:

```
PATH=/home/user/Trash
for file in $PATH
do
$file | echo "deleted on" | date -r $file
done
echo "Enter the filename to undelete from the above list:"
```

EDIT: So I realized that I don't need variables, I can just list all the files in the Trash directory and edit the output to what I want. I'm having a little trouble with my for statement though, I'm getting these two errors: ./undelete.sh: line 6: date: command not found
./undelete.sh: line 6: /home/user/Trash: Is a directory. So I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong in my for statement.

Here is the expected output:

```
file1 deleted on Tue Mar 16 17:15:34 CDT 2010
file2 deleted on Tue Mar 16 17:15:47 CDT 2010
Enter the filename to undelete from the above list:
```

Comment: What makes you think that attempting to `export` a variable from within a script would set in the parent shell?

Comment: I thought if you export something it goes to the global variable list? So then I should be able to pull them from the global list and add it in the shell for undelete.sh

Comment: That's not how it works. Also, a variable assignment will just override the value.

Comment: @Student You are trying to set the variable in the parent shell.  This isn't possible.  You'll need to change your approach.

Comment: @Student, if a variable is exported, it's visible to subprocesses. Otherwise, it's only visible to the current process and anything forked from it with no following exec (effectively, subshells). Under no circumstances can you propagate an environment variable from a process to its parent without having the parent explicitly trying to pull it in (as when a parent is running `eval "$(child)"`).

Comment: An option might be to `source` the scripts instead.  Try executing those by saying `. /path/to/script` or `source /path/to/script` instead.  But you shouldn't be doing things this way.

Comment: Exactly. There's no reason to try to have persistent variables like this when you could just store the metadata on the filesystem.

Comment: So if I'm not using persistent variables, how am I storing the file information/date moved/former directory? Also, if I use the . /path/to/script it will run the entire delete.sh which I don't want. I just want the values to come to the new shell so I can have a list of files moved so I can pick which one to move back to its former directory

Comment: @Student: you should probably be using shell functions instead of running scripts in subshells. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions

Comment: Had a brain fart and realized I could do it a different way, edited it to show the problem I am now having.

Comment: You are missing the `echo` command at the beginning of `$file | echo "deleted on" | date -r $file`. Also, given how different your edited question is from the original, this should really be a new question, as the existing answers to the original question no longer apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've accomplished what could be a workaround for what your scenario is trying to accomplish.

Basically you can enter echo "script2variable=$script1variable" >> script2.sh from script1.sh. Then use the source command to call that script later from any script you desire. Might have to just play with the theories involved.

Good Luck!

Delete Script file

```
#!/bin/bash
# delete.sh file
# Usage: ./delete.sh [filename]
#DATEDELETED=$(date) #not best solution for this kind of application
DIR=$(pwd)
fn=$1
#Specify your trash directory or partition
trash=~/trash
#Set path and filename for simple use in the script
trashed=$trash/$fn.tgz
#Send variables to new manifest script.
echo "#!/bin/bash" > $1.mf.sh
echo "DIR=$DIR" >> $1.mf.sh
# Questionable need? 
#echo "DATEDELETED=$DATEDELETED" >> $1.mf.sh
echo "mv $1 $DIR"  >> $1.mf.sh
echo Compressing
tar -cvpzf $trashed $1 $1.mf.sh
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo Compression Failed
else
    echo completed trash compression successfully
    echo Trashbin lists the file as $trashed
    rm $1 -f 
    rm $1.mf.sh -f
    echo file removed successfully
fi
exit 0
```

Restore Script File

```
#!/bin/bash
# restore.sh
# Usage: ./restore.sh 
# filename not required for this script, use index selection
fn=$1
#SET LOCATION OF TRASH DIRECTORY
trash=~/trash
listfile=($(ls $trash))
#SET COUNTER FOR LISTING FILES = 0
i=0
#THIS IS JUST A HEADER FOR YOUR OUTPUT.
clear #cleanup your shell
echo -e INDEX '\t' Filename '\t' '\t' '\t' Date Removed
#Echo a list of files from the array with the counter.
for FILES in "${listfile[@]}"
do
    echo -e $i '\t' $FILES '\t' "deleted on $(date -r $trash/$FILES)"
    let "i += 1"
done
#Output total number of items from the ls directory.
echo -e '\n' $i file\(s\) found in the trash!
# 1 Offset for 1 = 0, 2 = 1, and so on.
let "i -= 1"
#Require input of a single, double, or triple digit number only.
#Loop back prompt if not a number.
while true;
do
    read -p "Enter an index number for file restoration: " indx
    case $indx in
        [0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9] ) break ;;
        * ) read -p "Please enter a valid number 0-$i: " indx ;;
    esac
done
#
script=$(echo ${listfile[$indx]}|sed 's/\.tgz/\.mf.sh/g')
tar -xvpzf $trash/${listfile[$indx]}
rm $trash/${listfile[$indx]}
sleep 2
chmod +x $script
source $script
rm $script
```

Comment: what is the $trashrepo? Would this:                  PATH=/home/user/Trash
for file in $PATH
do
$file | echo "deleted on" | date -r $file
 not work?

Comment: I updated that script. I tried to modify it from a test path I was using to apply to your scenario listed. It's updated. The variable is just trash now.

Comment: I found a few other errors that were cleaned up. I guess I should have just used the home directory for ease of transferring the script here but its whatever. It's corrected now and syntaxes are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Run the script with `source`

```
source <yourscript>
```

or

```
. ./<yourscript>
```

In your case

```
. ./delete.sh && ./undelete.sh
```

Hope this will help